# query on one source to multi destination in arrangodb 3

Tags: arangodb

In `arrangodb` (version 3) I need a query to find all routes between one source to multi destination 
for example :

source : 5111454
destination : [5454,59812,54754,589895]

I need query to check relation between 5111454 and each one destination array

---

In fact I want to merge below four queries in one query:

```
FOR vertex[, edge]
IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH
**5111454** TO **5454**
GRAPH graphName
[OPTIONS options]

FOR vertex[, edge]
IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH
**5111454** TO **59812**
GRAPH graphName

FOR vertex[, edge]
IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH
**5111454** TO **54754**
GRAPH graphName
[OPTIONS options]


FOR vertex[, edge]
IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH
**5111454** TO **589895**
GRAPH graphName
[OPTIONS options]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the AQL graph traversal [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html).

You query could look like:

```
LET ids = [5454,59812,54754,589895]
FOR vertex, edge, path
IN ANY 5111454
GRAPH graphName
  FILTER vertex._id IN ids
  RETURN path
```

**Note:** The startVertex (5111454) has to be the id from the document (field `_id`) the same belongs to the `ids` array if your `FILTER` works with `_id`.